# Powershell Arrays and Custom Objects

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to understand how to use object in combination with arrays. I have build myself a function to test around.

Here my Script:

```
Function Show-DiskInfo {

    $HWDisks =  Get-PhysicalDisk

    $HardwareInfo = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Info = "Backupserver Hardware Info"
        "----" = "----------------"
    }


    $x = 1
    foreach ($disk in $HWDisks) {

        $HardwareInfo | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name Disk$x -Value ($disk.FriendlyName + " " + [math]::Round(($disk.Size/1GB),2) + " GB")
        $x++
    } 


    $HardwareInfo | Format-List 
 }

 Show-DiskInfo
```

My expected result would look like this:

Info    : Disk Info
----    : ----------------
Disks   : (first disk)
Disks   : (second disk)
Disks   : (etc.)

But the result I get looks like:

Info    : Disk Info
----    : ----------------
Disks   : {(first disk), (second disk), (etc.)}

My guess would be it has something to do with the way I display my result (not looping through all Disks when displaying). Is my guess correct (and if so what do I need to change) or am I completly of the track?

**EDIT:**

With @AdminOfThings suggestion I was be able to solve the problem.

The code now looks like:

```
Function Show-DiskInfo {

    $HWDisks =  Get-PhysicalDisk

    $HardwareInfo = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Info = "Backupserver Hardware Info `n----------------"
    }


    $x = 1
    foreach ($disk in $HWDisks) {

        $HardwareInfo | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name Disk$x -Value ($disk.FriendlyName + " " + [math]::Round(($disk.Size/1GB),2) + " GB")
        $x++
    } 


    $HardwareInfo | Format-List 
 }

 Show-DiskInfo
```

Comment: Your main issue is that you are completely building the `$DiskInfo` array before ever adding it to the `$HardwareInfo` object. When you finally do add it, it is already an array or collection, and you are assigning it to a property. A collection as a property will have the default output format of `{item1, item2, item3}`. For the desired output, you need to move the `Add-Member` command inside of the `foreach ($Disk in $HWDisks) {}` loop. Based on this code alone, `$DiskInfo` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you are completely building the `$DiskInfo` array before ever adding it to the `$HardwareInfo` object. When you finally do add it, it is already an array or collection, and you are assigning it to a property. A collection as a property will have the default output format of `{item1, item2, item3}`. For the desired output, you need to move the `Add-Member` command inside of the `foreach ($Disk in $HWDisks) {}` loop. Based on this code alone, `$DiskInfo` as an array is not necessary. See below for edits.

```
Function Show-DiskInfo {
    $HWDisks =  Get-PhysicalDisk

    $HardwareInfo = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
         Info = "Disk Info"
         "----" = "----------------"
    }

    foreach ($Disk in $HWDisks) {       
         $HardwareInfo |
             Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Disks -Value ($Disk.FriendlyName + ($Disk.size/1GB) + " GB")
            }
    $HardwareInfo | Format-List Info,“----“,Disks
}
Show-DiskInfo
```

---

**Alternative Approach:**

What I do not know is if you are trying to replicate `Format-Table` or `Format-List` output. My personal preference would be to create a custom object that stores property and value pairs. If you have multiple objects, you can either store them in an array within the function or output each object from the function. If the purpose of the function is to gather disk information and format the output, then you will need to manage the array within the function.

Regarding formatting, I would not use the disk info custom object properties to manage formatting. It creates an inconsistency within the object because now you have properties that serve no real purpose other than setting up your formatting. I would just use the format operator (`-f`) format the output.

```
Function Show-DiskInfo {
    "Info : Disk Info"
    "---- : ----------------"
    foreach ($disk in Get-PhysicalDisk) {
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
                 FriendlyName = $disk.FriendlyName
                 Size = $disk.Size/1GB
        }
        "Disks : {0} ({1} GB)" -f $obj.FriendlyName,$obj.Size
    }
}
Show-DiskInfo
```

Comment: I am trying to replicate the `Format-List` output.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
Function Show-DiskInfo {
    $HWDisks =  Get-PhysicalDisk
    foreach ($disk in $HWDisks) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            FriendlyName = $disk.FriendlyName
            DiskSizeGB = [math]::Round(($disk.Size/1GB),2)
        }
    }

}
Show-DiskInfo
```

Your code is not really correct and it would be hard to explain everything. 
If you have questions, about the suggested edit, I would be more than happy to explain in details.

Hope it helps.

Comment: First of all thanks for the fast answer. Second is there a way to display the output of both values in one line of an list? And if so is there a way to add the gathered information into another custom object?

Comment: My next question would be what is the purpose of the ",2" in "[math]::Round(($disk.Size/1GB),2)" ?

Comment: You may try the following:

Comment: Sorry, I was on the road and didn't managed to respond correctly. 
You may try to use the function name, and pipe the output to Format-List: 
Show-DiskInfo | Format-List

The other thing is using the round method of Math type, rounds the output to the closest whole number. 
When using a second argument, like here 2, it would round to the second digit, after the decimal point.